# NET Framework project can't load assembly when referencing .NET Standard project

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

I have a .NET Framework Web project which references a .NET Standard class library.

When running the app I get:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.NameResolution, Version=4.0.0.0"
```

So I added the System.Net.NameResolution 4.3.0 nuget package to both of these projects.

I can't use package 4.0.0 as this would be a downgrade, so I added a binding redirect to the .NET Framework project:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.NameResolution" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

The app now acknowledges my redirect, but I still get the same error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.NameResolution, Version=4.0.0.0

Calling assembly : EnyimMemcachedCore, Version=1.1.1.11, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Source\myapp\src\Web\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\fraserb\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 4.0.0.0 redirected to 4.0.1.0.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Net.NameResolution, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/31e1be3d/fde97fa5/System.Net.NameResolution.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/31e1be3d/fde97fa5/System.Net.NameResolution/System.Net.NameResolution.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Source/myapp/src/Web/bin/System.Net.NameResolution.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Build Number
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Are you getting this error after upgrading your code from one .NET Framework to Next level or renaming sample project to create new project? If these are the case, then you have to check all the references of the projects and update those place accordingly. (I faced the same issue and resolved in this way).

Comment: Microsoft screwed-up semantic versioning pretty badly, but it truly is 4.0.1.0.  Most obvious explanation is that you actually got 4.0.0.0 deployed into your build directory.  You'll need to find out why you need this binding redirect in the first place.  Jack up the build verbosity to Detailed so you can see version conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out binding redirect newVersion should have targeted 4.0.2.0 rather than 4.0.1.0, and everything loaded successfully after that.

(I realised it was 4.0.2.0 after double checking the version of the DLL being loaded - you can view this in Assembly Explorer)